# Custom wordpress Form submission

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to insert data into database table through custom php form in wordpress. I don't want to use/create plugins/hooks. just simple form for client so he can edit himself whenever he want.

I tried

```
if($_POST['submit'])
{< submit to db >
} else {
< display html form ><br>
}
```

with action="" .   this redirect to the same page without any error on page + in console. javascript validations on fields are working perfect.

I tried another solution by creating a php file in themes folder, and setting action="../that_file.php", which gave 404 error.

Any other solution?

Comment: **client so he can edit himself whenever he want** - have you looked into form plugins such as Formidable? https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/formidable/

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Formidable](https://en-gb.wordpress.org/plugins/formidable/) or [ACF](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) to build your form, you will lose less time for any update on your form, also, you could have a view in the dashboard to manage your user's response, that should be easier for you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys I found a way. I use Contact form 7 for form and CFDB plugin to save that form data to db.

I had to send confirmation email after submission so Contact form 7 did it for me.